# Strongloop fails to install in Windows 7, sqlite3@3.0.5 Failed to exec install script

Tags: node.js, sqlite, installation, strongloop

I followed the strongloop pre installation requirments (http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SL/Installing+Node+and+StrongLoop+on+Windows) and everything was set without problems. However , each time I execute

```
npm install -g npm
```

the installation fails. In the npm-debug.log I see the reason for the failure is

```
info sqlite3@3.0.5 Failed to exec install script
```

sqlite3 was installed successfully in the global modules.

Comment: Try clearing your cache with `npm cache clear` and re-running `npm install -g strongloop`.

Comment: I tried that too and still had the error.

Comment: I meant to do it at the time I commented, not asking whether you had tried that when you saw the error. There was a problem with a release of one of the dependencies and it has seen been rolled back. Clearing your cache and trying again should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened my CMD in administrator's mode, and by default it opens in

```
c:\Windows\system32
```

executing

```
  c:\Windows\system32> npm install -g strongloop
```

fails with the error in the question. However, executing from the C:\ is OK.

```
C:\> npm install -g npm
```